# Screen Jumps/Scrolls cursor out of view during editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have some fields on my app as soon as i go to write at any time the cursor jump to top of screen.

I tried write some selectors but Not solved like:

```
html,body {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

"I expect the output https://ibb.co/PjdBcBC ."

"The output is https://ibb.co/Jd9yY7D but that is wrong."

Comment: can you provide more details? It seems like css position property issue but need to inspect more. the code snippet would be better.

Comment: No, it not seems property like position. Bummer limited in during write at any field the keyboard show and the cursor go to jump to top and that described at links.

Comment: just inspect once it could be the z-index of your editor is less than your header that's why it is going behind it. And still there should be position relative to the parent container and position absolute of the editor container.

Comment: No man the problem is the cursor jumps to top no my header is relative and cursor  is behind!

Comment: kindly share the code snippet or jsfiddle that might be helpful to debug your problem